# How to check if a MapState is empty in flink 1.8

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an application where I am reading all the data from a DB for the first time and add it to MapState. Here is my RichCoFlatMapFunction

```
private transient MapState<String, Record> mapState;

@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    mapState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<String, Record>("recordState", 
                   TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>(){}), TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Record>() {})));        
}

@Override
public void flatMap1(Record record, Collector<OutputRecord> collector) throws Exception {
    readForFirstTime();
    mapState.put(item.getId(), item);
}

@Override
public void flatMap2(Item item, Collector<OutputRecord> collector) throws Exception {
    readForFirstTime();
    Record record = mapState.get(item.getId);
    System.out.println("Item arrived at time:"+ item.getTimestamp() + 
       ". Record at the exact same time:" + record.toString());
}

private void readForFirstTime() {
    // I need a mechanism here to detect if recordState is empty
    // then only listAllFromDB

    for(Record record: listAllFromDB) {
        mapState.put(record.getId(), record);
    }
}
```

So when I start my application from snapshot, I assume MapState will contain data and I do not want to read from DB. How can I check if the MapState is empty or contains data ?

Comment: I think your approach above would give you a copy of what's in the DB for every unique key in your data stream - is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I need a copy of what's in the DB. But how do I check if my MapState is empty ?

Comment: I'm either not understanding your goal, or you misunderstood my question. Do you **really** want a complete copy of every record from your DB stored in state for **every** unique key seen in any record in your data stream?

Comment: Yes, I need complete copy of every record from my DB

Comment: Before we go further on this - are you keying by `item.getId()`? If so, then you don't want to use `MapState<String, Record>`, you want `ValueState<Record>`. And you'd check to see if it's there by whether the value is null. But then you wouldn't load all of the DB records inside the function, you'd have a stream coming from the DB, keyed by the same item ID, and use a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`.

Comment: Makes sense. If application started just now and there is no update on the DB, there will be no item in the db stream. I received an `Item` and  `ValueState<Record>` is null for the key `item.getId()`, here I do want the `Record` for given `item.getId()`. How can I populate this `Record` if there is no entry in DB stream ?

Comment: At this point it might be better to post a new question, using the above logic. But to confirm, you're asking about how to do a (stateful) join, where one side is data from your DB, and the other is a stream of records, yes?

Comment: Yes, I want a stateful join between 2 sources, one is a stream and other is read from DB with updates made using stream.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to load database data only once, usually you do this at the **open(.)** method. Or you can use another **MapState** to the database data and use the MapState::isEmpty().

Comment: This cannot be done in the open() method, because when open() is called there's no way of knowing for which keys this task is going to be processing records. The API will not allow you to read or write the MapState's entries during the open() -- this can only be done later, during flatMap1 and flatMap2 (while processing stream records), because only then is there a key in the runtime context.

Comment: Due to some constraints I have to only use Flink 1.8 in which there is no `isEmpty()` for `MapState`